# Django haystack elasticsearch autocomplete don't work

Tags: django, elasticsearch, autocomplete, django-haystack

In database I have products with names: "Product 1", "Product 2" and so on. Search for "Produc" should return many values, but I get nothing. 
My index:

```
from haystack import indexes

from .models import Product


class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)
    id = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='id')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    slug = indexes.CharField(model_attr='slug')
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')
    content_auto = indexes.NgramField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return Product

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

results from shell:

```
In [3]: SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto='produc')
Out[3]: []

In [4]: SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto='product')
Out[4]: [<SearchResult: catalogue.product (pk=u'4')>, <SearchResult:      
catalogue.product (pk=u'9')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product  
(pk=u'11')>,  <SearchResult: catalogue.product (pk=u'16')>,   
<SearchResult: catalogue.product (pk=u'23')>, <SearchResult:  
catalogue.product (pk=u'28')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product  
(pk=u'30')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product (pk=u'35')>, <SearchResult: 
catalogue.product (pk=u'42')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product 
(pk=u'47')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product (pk=u'54')>, <SearchResult: 
catalogue.product (pk=u'59')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product 
(pk=u'61')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product (pk=u'66')>, <SearchResult: 
catalogue.product (pk=u'73')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product 
(pk=u'78')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product (pk=u'80')>, <SearchResult: 
catalogue.product (pk=u'85')>, <SearchResult: catalogue.product 
(pk=u'92')>, u'...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue if using an `EdgeNgramField` for `content_auto` as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you just added the `content_auto` field, you may need to run `manage.py rebuild_index` to create the updated index.

Comment: I run rebuild_index after every change. Yes, I have the same issue when use EdgeNgramField.